# Changes not being shown in changed MVC index.cshtml

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, visual-studio-2015, localhost

I am learning MVC.  I am following a tutorial and have made a simple text change to my index.cshtml.  In order for changes to show I have to restart VS, in which case the changes do show.  I have tried different browsers.  I have tried clearing all cache.  I have tried building before running.  I am using VS Professional 2015.

Any suggestions on how to see my changes without having to restart VS each time?

Comment: refresh the page in browser

Comment: Have you tried a server refresh? (Ctrl + F5 in IE)

Comment: yes, tried both with no success.

Comment: Can you post what did you change actually? And how does it appear after change

Comment: I changed <h3>Hello MVC!</h3> to <h3>Hello MVC!!!!!!!!!</h3> and it still just shows the former

Comment: Did you save before refreshing? Really you should stop debugging and run again. You shouldn't have to restart VS

Comment: Yep.  It really should be simple, but it continues to not show changes.

Comment: So... I opened a completely different MVC project.  Made an edit and it successfully showed changes without having to restart VS.  I went back to the original project and it will not update without restarting VS.  I know that it is not my code change that is causing problems since it runs fine after restarting (and it is simply some extra exclamation marks).  Feeling a little baffled.

Comment: I have not made any changes (other than to the text) and now it is working fine.  It takes a long time(54s) to load: "Waiting for localhost".  Is it possible that this is the culprit of some sorts?

Answer (score 0):

First of all try server refreshing (CTRL + F5 / Shift + F5 / CTRL + R depending on the browser).

If this doesn't work, and if you're just running your app locally with visual studio, just RE-RUN (shift + F5, F5) and make sure you also stop the asp.net development server.

If you've installed the MVC proyect as a site in your iis, just restart the iis. In case this isn't enough, you can recycle the application pool.
And even if all of this doesn't work, just delete all asp.net temporary files (this [Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms366723) explains where they are located).

My personal experience: try the first one more than once, it always works.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the actual problem was, but a reboot solved my issues.